# I get DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'productID'

Tags: c#, mysql, data-binding

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="check.aspx.cs" Inherits="check" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
 <style>
            h1 {
            font-family: 'Lucida Handwriting';
            text-align: center;
            margin: 50px;
            font-size: 50px;
        }

        .word {
            font-family: 'Lucida Handwriting';
            margin: 50px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        body {
            background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-3UIjuTrbAI8/Uihk5uaH_lI/AAAAAAAAAuk/gcn5XlQ9kyI/s640/Top+10+best+Simple+Awesome+Background+Images+for+Your+Website+or+Blog2.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: black;
        }
        .transbox {
            margin: 30px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 0px;
            opacity: 0.75;
            /*filter: alpha(opacity=50);*/
        }

            .topnav a {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

                .topnav a:hover {
                    background-color: burlywood;
                    color: black;
                }

                .topnav a.active {
                    background-color: #4CAF50;
                    color: white;
                }

        .topnar a {
            float: right;
            background-color: black;
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

            .topnar a:hover {
                background-color: burlywood;
                color: black;
            }

        .txtstyle {
            width: 300px;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
            -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
            transition: 0.5s;
            outline: none;
        }

            .txtstyle:focus {
                border: 3px solid #555;
            }

             .btnlogout {
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                font-family:'Lucida Handwriting';
                float:right;
            }
     .auto-style2 {
         width: 146px;
     }
     .auto-style3 {
         width: 233px;
     }
     .auto-style5 {
         width: 172px;
     }
     .auto-style6 {
         width: 141px;
     }
     .auto-style7 {
         width: 233px;
         height: 26px;
     }
     .auto-style10 {
         width: 141px;
         height: 26px;
     }
     .auto-style11 {
         height: 26px;
         width: 140px;
     }
     .auto-style14 {
         width: 175px;
     }
     .auto-style15 {
         height: 26px;
         width: 175px;
     }
     .auto-style16 {
         height: 26px;
         width: 172px;
     }
     .auto-style17 {
         height: 26px;
         width: 146px;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <div class="topnar">
                <a href="adminpage.aspx">Manage</a>
                <a href="orderlist.aspx">Orderlist</a>
            </div>
            <div class="topnav">
                <a class="active" href="menuhome.aspx">Home</a>
                <a href="menuchicken.aspx">Chicken & Fish</a>
                <a href="menupasta.aspx">Pasta</a>
                <a href="menuwrap.aspx">Sandwich & Wrap</a>
                <a href="menuside.aspx">Side Order</a>
                <a href="menusoup.aspx">Salad & Soup</a>

            </div>
        <div>
            Order ID :
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtorid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            Secret Code :
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtcode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btncheck" runat="server" Text="Check" OnClick="btncheck_Click" />
            <br />
            <br />
            </div>
            <div class="transbox">
            Reservation details:
         <table border="1">
             <tr>
                 <td class="auto-style7">ID</td>
                 <td class="auto-style15">Reserved Date</td>
                 <td class="auto-style11">Reserved Time</td>
                 <td class="auto-style10">Name</td>
                 <td class="auto-style11">Handphone</td>
                 <td class="auto-style17">TableNumber</td>
                 <td class="auto-style16">Pax</td>

             </tr>

             <asp:ListView ID="listView" runat="server">

                 <ItemTemplate>

                     <tr>
                         <td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
                         <td><%# Eval("Datebook") %></td>
                         <td><%# Eval("TimeFrom") %></td>
                         <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                         <td><%# Eval("Handphone") %></td>
                         <td><%# Eval("TableNumber") %></td>
                         <td><%# Eval("Pax") %></td>


                     </tr>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:ListView>

         </table>
            <br />
            <br />
         Food Ordered:
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Food ID</td>
                <td>Food Name</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Total</td>

            </tr>

            <asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">

                <ItemTemplate>

                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("productid") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Foodname") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("quantity") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("price") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("total") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>

        </table>

        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, this is my code. I use subquery to combine some fields in my ***SQL-statement*** and I can't get the value after subquery. Also, I get this error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name 'productID'

Anyone know how to solve it? I had checked all the column names. This sql statement **can run in MYSQL database but not in code**. Thanks!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class check : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmmd = new MySqlCommand();
        connection.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=pf;UID=root;PASSWORD=password;";
        connection.Open();
        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM booking where secret = '"+ txtcode.Text + "' and id = '"+ txtorid.Text +"'";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdText, connection);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(t);
        listView.DataSource = t;
        listView.DataBind();
        listView.Visible = true;
        connection.Close();

        MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=pf;Uid=root;Pwd=password;");
        MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand();
        Conn.Open();
        Command.Connection = Conn;
        Command.CommandText = "SELECT productid, (select name from menu where id = productid)as Foodname, price, quantity, price * quantity as total from salesdetail where salesid = (select id from booking where secret = 'ypnok3bd' and id = 'SSD00000000000000001') ";

        string productid = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        string Foodname = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        string price = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        string total = Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(d);
        listView1.DataSource = d;
        listView1.DataBind();
        listView1.Visible = true;
        Conn.Close();

    }

    protected void btncheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you really should try/learn to do things the correct way, there are so many things wrong, that are considered bad - very bad - practise and it will lead to unnecessary errors. 1. you dont use parameters to build your SQL query 2. you arent disposing your Connection/command/sqldataadapter 3. you are hard coding your password 4. you arent re-using your connection even though its in the same method 5. the class name doesnt apply any naming convention I have seen so far ``check``

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the wrong command for the DataAdapter or using the wrong column. Because you want to show `ProductID` in your view but the other SelectCommand selects that column. The one that you use for the adapter uses `SELECT * FROM booking` and the primary column of that table is `Id`.

---

Apart from that, you can't use `ExecuteScalar` to receive multiple different columns from a select query. Only the first column of the first record is returned. Instead you can use a `DataReader`:

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT productid, (select name from menu where id = productid)as Foodname, price, quantity, price * quantity as total from salesdetail where salesid = (select id from booking where secret = 'ypnok3bd' and id = 'SSD00000000000000001') ";

using(var rd = Command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(rd.Read())
    {
       string productid = rd.GetInt32(0).ToString();
       string foodname = rd.GetString(1);
       string price = rd.GetDecimal(2).ToString();
       string total = rd.GetDecimal(3).ToString();
   }
}
```

I have presumed the types of the columns. Change accordingly if you get an exception.

Comment: Another error :"Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()"

Comment: Hmm... Now there is no error but the data didn't fill the listview.